# How to stop my animation

Tags: html, css

I want the block to go from one point to another. 
In the Fiddle you can see that after the animation, the block goes back to it's first position.

How can I prevent that?

http://jsfiddle.net/2nT2S/

**the css**

```
div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:black;
position:relative;
animation:myfirst 2s;
-webkit-animation:myfirst 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
from { left:0px; top:0px; }
to { left:0px; top:200px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from { left:0px; top:0px; }
to { left:0px; top:200px; }
}    
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply add the `forwards` [animation-fill-mode](http://www.valhead.com/2013/01/04/tutorial-css-animation-fill-mode/) to the animation:

```
animation:myfirst 2s forwards;
-webkit-animation:myfirst 2s forwards; /* Safari and Chrome */
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nT2S/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to animations, but I think it can be achieved by adding `top:200px;` to the div

here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/2nT2S/2/